# this.props.data.maps is not a function ONLY when this.props.data.length is in the same block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

I'm getting some weird behavior.  The this.props.data below is an array from my Redux store and I can see that it is not undefined or empty when this error occurs.

When I take out the `this.props.data.length > 5` below, everything works great.. but once I add it in, my project throws the error `this.props.data.maps is not a function`.

```
    {
                  ((this.props.data) !== undefined) ? (
                    ((this.props.data).length > 0) ? (
                      (this.props.data).map((index) => {

                      var numberSize = '';
                      if (index.number > 100000 === 0) {
                        numberSize = 'Huge number';
                      } else if (index.number > 1000 === 0) {
                        numberSize = 'Big number'
                      } else if (index.number > 100 === 0) {
                        numberSize = 'Medium number';
                      } else {
                        numberSize = 'Small number';
                      }
                        return (
                          <div>
                            {numberSize}
                          </div>
                        );
                      })
//..beginning here
                      ((this.props.data).length < 5) ? (
                         <button onClick={this.addToArray}>Add a number to the data</button>           
                      ) : (
                        <span>The data array is full (5 objects). No Numbers can be added.</span>
                      )
//..ending here.  If I take this out, everything runs fine.
                    ) : (
                      <button onClick={this.addToArray}>Add a number to the data</button>           
                    )
                  ) : (
                     <button onClick={this.addToArray}>Add a number to the data</button>           
                  )
     }
```

Does anyone understand why adding in the `this.props.data.length > 5` is throwing the error that `this.props.data.maps is not a function`?

Thanks

Comment: Missing closing `)` at conditional operator? Also, is a process expected after `.map()` call?

Comment: What is expected logic?

Comment: I have updated my code to clarify with an example of what I meant by "logic".  Yes, a process occurs within each loop of the `.map()` call, which the updated code should help clarify as well.  Let me know if not.  Can you clarify where you see a missing `)`?

Comment: The issue is not `.map()`, but expression following `.map()`

Comment: `((data).length < 5) ? (
                         <button></button>           
                      ) : (
                        <span></span>
                      )`  Is this where you see a missing `)`?

Comment: No, at first glance there was a missing `)` at close of entire conditional operator. Though if you see missing parenthesis there, you could correct the omission. `(data).length < 5) ? ( <button></button> ) : ( <span></span> )` is the issue with `javascript`

Comment: @guest271314  I tried adding && or || as you suggested.  The error isn't thrown, but both caused the first div within the .map function not to show

Comment: Note, have little experience with `reactjs`. Can you write the logic in your own form of descriptive identifiers? Form example, if x is true performTaskA else performTaskB and performTaskC. What are you trying to achieve logically?

Comment: I am trying to render a div for each object in the array.  If the array is less than a particular length, I would like a button to show that can add another object to the array.  If the array is not less than that particular length, then I would like no button to show (but still the div's for each object to show).

Comment: Not sure about `reactjs`, you can try chaining `.length` call to `.map()` `.map().length < 5 ?  <button onClick={this.addToArray}>Add a number to the data</button>:<span>The data array is full (5 objects). No Numbers can be added.</span>`

Comment: `.map` is essentially a `for` loop on the array, so chaining the `.length` to it throws an `Unexpected token` error since the compiler expect the loop for the `.map` to begin once it is called.
I do know that the individual pieces I have work, since if I do one at a time, they both work.  It just seems that when both `(this.props.data).map((index)` and `(this.props.data).length` are in the the same parent `{ }` then the error I am getting is thrown.
Lastly, I would be happy to move to a chat if you would like to start it (I can't start it since my reputation is not high enough--2 points shy)

Comment: Not certain can help if issue is `reactjs` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing `)` at conditional operator. More importantly, following `.map()` call it is not clear what logic is.

Omitting unnecessary parenthesis we find that there will be a syntax error following `.map()` call if `&&` `AND` or `||` `OR` are not utilized. Which leads us back to what expected result of portion of `javascript` following `.map()` is?

```js
this.props = {data:[1,2,3]};

this.props.data !== undefined 
  ? this.props.data.length > 0 
    ? this.props.data.map((index) => {
        console.log(index);
      //...some logic for the return
        return (index * 10);
      })
      // && 
      /*
        Syntax error here
      */
    //..beginning here
    this.props.data.length < 5
      ? console.log("less than 5", this.props.data.length)
      : console.log("greater than 5", this.props.data.length)
    //..ending here.  If I take this out, everything runs fine.
   : console.log("inner")
  : console.log("outer")
```

```js
this.props = {data:[1,2,3]};

this.props.data !== undefined 
  ? this.props.data.length > 0 
    ? this.props.data.map((index) => {
        console.log(index);
      //...some logic for the return
        return (index * 10);
      })
      && 
      /*
        what are you trying to achieve here?
      */
    //..beginning here
    this.props.data.length < 5
      ? console.log("less than 5", this.props.data.length)
      : console.log("greater than 5", this.props.data.length)
    //..ending here.  If I take this out, everything runs fine.
   : console.log("inner")
  : console.log("outer")
```

Comment: I tried adding && or ||, but this causes the first div within the `.map` function not to show (which be the `return (index * 10);` line in your example)